# Getting this as Error "status": 404, "error": "Not Found", "exception": "#<ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User without an ID>",

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, jwt

So i followed this Tutorial on here

https://dev.to/codesalley/ruby-on-rails-api-simple-authentication-with-jwt-1nfe

As I am learning Ruby on Rails by myself and I am learning to Design a REST API , i am not using devise as i want to handle things myself for good understanding.

However things went Awry, and I am stuck somewhere

I have created the controllers sessions and todos and I have written my respective Code inside of the controllers respectively.

Fast forward to what the challenge is.

I want to use the Token gotten from the Login (As tested on Postman), so I can use it to pass information from the Header inside Postman and I am getting This as an Error

Here is my Error

```
{
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "exception": "#<ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User without an ID>",
}
```

And other Myriad of Errors.
Login and Register works fine they return the Tokens respectively. Testing on Login Shows the token as requested below

[image: login.png]

Now when i want to use the token as stated above , i get the error on postman

[image: user1-test.png]

My code Looks thus

**session_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def signup
      user = User.new(email: params[:email], password: params[:password])
  
      # if user is saved
      if user.save
        # we encrypt user info using the pre-define methods in application controller
        token = encode_user_data({ user_data: user.id })
  
        # return to user
        render json: { token: token }
      else
        # render error message
        render json: { message: "invalid credentials" }
      end
    end
  
    def login
      user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
  
      # you can use bcrypt to password authentication
      if user && user.password == params[:password]
  
        # we encrypt user info using the pre-define methods in application controller
        token = encode_user_data({ user_data: user.id })
  
        # return to user
        render json: { token: token }
      else
        render json: { message: "invalid credentials" }
      end
    end
  end
```

**todos_controller.rb**

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController

    # authentication is the method we define in application_controller.rb to check request.headers['token']
    
      before_action :authentication
    
      # GET /todos
      def index
        @todos = Todo.all
        render json: @todos
      end

      def create
        todo = Todo.new(title: params[:title])
        if todo.save
            render json: { message: "Todo successfully saved" }
        else
            render json: { message: "Todo list cannot be saved!" }
        end
      end


    end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    SECRET = "friend"
  
    def authentication
      # making a request to a secure route, token must be included in the headers
      decode_data = decode_user_data(request.headers["token"])
      # getting user id from a nested JSON in an array.
      user_data = decode_data[0]["user_id"] unless !decode_data
      # find a user in the database to be sure token is for a real user
      user = User.find(user_data&.id)
  
      # The barebone of this is to return true or false, as a middleware
      # its main purpose is to grant access or return an error to the user
  
      if user
        return true
      else
        render json: { message: "invalid credentials" }
      end
    end
  
    # turn user data (payload) to an encrypted string  [ A ]
    def encode_user_data(payload)
      token = JWT.encode payload, SECRET, "HS256"
      return token
    end
  
    # turn user data (payload) to an encrypted string  [ B ]
    def encode_user_data(payload)
      JWT.encode payload, SECRET, "HS256"
    end
  
    # decode token and return user info, this returns an array, [payload and algorithms] [ A ]
    def decode_user_data(token)
      begin
        data = JWT.decode token, SECRET, true, { algorithm: "HS256" }
        return data
      rescue => e
        puts e
      end
    end
  
    # decode token and return user info, this returns an array, [payload and algorithms] [ B ]
    def decode_user_data(token)
      begin
        JWT.decode token, SECRET, true, { algorithm: "HS256" }
      rescue => e
        puts e
      end
    end
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post "/auth/login", to: "sessions#login"
  post "/auth/signup", to: "sessions#signup"

  #resources :todos
  get "/todos", to: "todos#index"
  post "/todos", to: "todos#create"

end
```

How Do i resolve this? Please let me know.

**Edit**

So i replaced these things as said in the answer.

and i have this Error

[image: error.png]

With this code

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    SECRET = "yoursecretword"

    def authentication
        user = authenticate_with_http_token do |token,_|
                 begin 
                   decode_data = JWT.decode token, SECRET, true, { algorithm: "HS256" }
                   user_id = decode_data.dig(0,"user_id")
                   user = User.find(user_id) if user_id 
                rescue JWT::DecodeError => e
                   logger.info "DecodeError: #{e.message}" and nil
                end
               end 
        user || render json: { message: "invalid credentials" }
      end
end
```

**Edits 2**

Now i am trying to access http://127.0.0.1:3000/todos with a Bearer , and I am getting "invalid Credentials"

See my code

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  SECRET = "yoursecretword"

  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods

  def authentication
    user = authenticate_with_http_token do |token, _|
      begin
        decode_data = JWT.decode token, SECRET, true, { algorithm: "HS256" }
        user_id = decode_data.dig(0, "user_id")
        user = User.find(user_id) if user_id
      rescue JWT::DecodeError => e
        logger.info "DecodeError: #{e.message}" and nil
      end
    end
    user || render(json: { message: "invalid credentials" })
  end

  def encode_user_data(payload)
    JWT.encode(payload, SECRET, "HS256")
  end

  def decode_user_data(token)
    begin
      JWT.decode(token, SECRET, true, { algorithm: "HS256" })
    rescue => e
      puts e
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

What am I wrongly doing?

Comment: You need to stop doing `rescue => e`. This is an anti-pattern know as Pokémon Exception Handling (Gotta catch them all). It will catch exceptions that you should not be handling and make debugging impossible. Only rescue specific exception classes that you know what to do with.

Comment: OK pls what do I do, as I am learning?

Comment: Don't do `rescue => e`.  Do `rescue SomeSpecificException => e`.

Comment: @max, what i mean is, in the class ApplicationController < ActionController::API, could you kindly show me what to remove. and how it should be? I am learning so i do not make mistakes

Comment: There is just so much code here with so many issues so its hard to know where to even start. The `authentication` method should check if `request.headers["token"]` is actually present and bail early. `user = User.find(user_data&.id)`  will raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception if the record is not found so the line `if user` will never be reached.

Comment: I looked at the tutorial link it's not good at all and littered with issues like this. I would find something better to base your code off.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the code posted as it relates to the error:

1. Right now your are looking for `request.headers["token"]` but this does not exist as the header is "Authorization", so your actually calling `decode_user_data(nil)`
2. Then `decode_user_data` raises an error because `JWT::decode` does not expect the `token` to be `nil` and raises `JWT::DecodeError` telling you so.
3. This error is trapped by `rescue` and results in a `puts` call (which you should see in your logs) and returns `nil` (because that's what `puts` returns).
4. This causes `user_data = decode_data[0]["user_id"] unless !decode_data` to follow the unless branch because `!nil == true`
5. This then causes `user = User.find(user_data&.id)` to be `user = User.find(nil)` resulting in your ultimate error.

Rather than going through all the hassle of trying to parse the header Rails actually provides you with a convenience method [`authenticate_with_http_token`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Token/ControllerMethods.html#method-i-authenticate_or_request_with_http_token) for this purpose. Also See [HTTP Token authentication](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Token.html)

We could potentially modify your code to something like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods

  def authentication
    user = authenticate_with_http_token do |token,_|
             begin 
               decode_data = JWT.decode token, SECRET, true, { algorithm: "HS256" }
               user_id = decode_data.dig(0,"user_id")
               user = User.find(user_id) if user_id 
            rescue JWT::DecodeError => e
               logger.info "DecodeError: #{e.message}" and nil
            end
          end 
    user || render(json: { message: "invalid credentials" })
  end
end
```

Comment: pls see edits. I have done as you have said. just one error

Comment: @GilmeriGolano fixed although if that is what tripped you up I would highly recommend some basic tutorials on ruby itself before you start trying to build APIs.

Comment: Gives a totally different Error NoMethodError (undefined method `authenticate_with_http_token' for #<TodosController:0x00000000008700>):

Comment: @GilmeriGolano okay Add this line to the top of your `ApplicationController`: `include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods`

Comment: i am getting "invalid credentials" i think something is wrong. Please see edits. I have done all you have said.

Comment: @GilmeriGolano that means that your token cannot decode correctly look in your logs for "INFO DecodeError: " and figure out what the error message is or just comment out the `begin` and the `rescue` block and see what error it is throwing.